# Why is it that people send questions from here over to 'Worldbuilding' even if they don’t fit there either?

Tags: discussion

Recently a [user](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/80200/darkorse) made a [post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/189468/trying-to-build-a-real-flying-saucer-v-2-0) on [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) about making a flying saucer in real life stating that he was told to go to Worldbuilding by a user on Physics Stack Exchange. Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to view the original deleted question or the comments on it, but it was decided that the question **did not fit on Worldbuilding** because it is about **real world** problems.

This is of course an issue. Neither site wants to have questions that don't fit it. I'm not sure if there were other issues with the original question, but on both Worldbuilding questions there were numerous other issues. Is there a reason these opinion based/improper/IRL questions get redirected to Worldbuilding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comment on the Physics post was:

> Welcome! For guidance about why this was closed, see our explanations of non-mainstream physics and engineering. If you’re constructing fiction, you might try Worldbuilding. rob♦ Oct 23 at 21:26

where some links were in the original text but didn't copy-paste over and aren't relevant. So in this instance, it was made clear to the user that if it is fictional, Worldbuilding might be a place to go. The user seemed to ignore that criteria and it ended up closed on WB -- which is something we can't really address I suppose.

We do try to take care to not migrate questions we aren't certain are on topic somewhere else, so I think this was about all we could do here.

Comment: ah, so its a bad combination of confusion from the original user i see